# Problemas al ingresar a mi IP pública estática

Tags: apache, debian

Presento actualmente un problema el cual he buscado y no he dado con la solución; espero me puedan ayudar:

Tengo una IP pública: `190.xxx.xx.xx` y la he asignado a una de las tarjetas de red de mi servidor local. El punto es que puedo ingresar desde la red local a esa IP y abre la página principal de Apache, lo cual no debería porque en la carpeta `/var/www/html` hay un archivo que redirecciona a una carpeta.

Dejo las capturas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería de redireccionar a una carpeta dentro de `/var/www/html`. Por el contrario, ingresando desde la IP local `192.xx.xx.xx` sí ingresa donde debería.

¿Alguien sabe cómo arreglar esto? He intentado todo lo que sé hacer (que no es mucho tampoco).

Comment: Has configurado el sitio en `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default` ? Que archivo tienes en tu carpeta ? Los archivos que por defecto se abren son `index.php` o `index.html`

Comment: Estan configurado correctamente, ya verifique los archivos que cree en /etc/apache2/sites-available ... tengo varios virtualhosts en archivos separados